# Migrating U2F to WebAuthn gem in Ruby, where to get the parameters for AuthenticatorAttestationResponse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webauthn, fido-u2f

I have a couple of questions about the WebAuthn gem and the use of U2fMigrator.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction about it.
I am in the step just after converting my old U2F credentials using U2fMigrator.

```
migrated_credential = WebAuthn::U2fMigrator.new(
        app_id: my_domain,
        certificate: u2f_registration.certificate,
        key_handle: u2f_registration.key_handle,
        public_key: u2f_registration.binary_public_key,
        counter: u2f_registration.counter
)
```

The documentation says: *“U2fMigrator class quacks like WebAuthn::AuthenticatorAttestationResponse”* but without **verify** implementation.

Does that mean I need to create an instance of this **AuthenticatorAttestationResponse** for authentication?

If so. Where I should get this data from?

```
assertion_response = WebAuthn::AuthenticatorAssertionResponse.new(
        credential_id: '',
        authenticator_data: '',
        client_data_json: '',
        signature: '',
 )
```

I am guessing that will allow me to authenticate the new migrated credentials like this:

```
assertion_response.verify(
        WebAuthn::Credential.options_for_get(:extensions => { appid: my_domain }).challenge,
        allowed_creadentials: migrated_credential.credential,
        rp_id: my_domain
)
```

And also, I am guessing I don't need to re-register these credentials yet.

I am following this documentation:

- https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby/blob/master/docs/u2f_migration.md
- https://github.com/castle/ruby-u2f
- https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby/blob/master/README.md#authentication

**UPDATE 1**

I've found this cool explanation [in this guide](https://webauthn.guide/)
[image: The assertion object]

I will dig into it and I'll post the solution if I can find it.

**UPDATE 2**

I've spent the whole week trying to get the *authenticatorAssertionResponse*
[image: assertion]

from

[image: get]

Unfortunately, I only get a message saying I don't have a key registered:
[image: error]

I'm passing through the *extension* and *appid* where the U2F credential was registered originally. I wonder if it stoped working now the deprecation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

`U2fMigrator` is instantiated with data that's already stored in your database. Instances of it respond to the same methods as `AuthenticatorAttestationResponse`, except it misses a `verify` method since the data was already verified in the past. In other words: the migrator behaves nearly the same as a freshly WebAuthn registered authenticator and it is meant to be used as such.

> Does that mean I need to create an instance of this
> AuthenticatorAttestationResponse for authentication?

Yes. The `AuthenticatorAttestationResponse` is instantiated with browser data from the WebAuthn `navigator.credentials.get` call. This in itself is unrelated to the U2F migration question, except for the part where the data comes from for its `verify` method. This comes either from a migrator instance (in the "real time conversion" approach) or is retrieved from the database.

Hope that makes sense, PRs welcome to improve the docs!